# Check if update happened in put request

Tags: php, mysql, rest, phalcon

I am new at PHP. We are creating REST API in Phalcon and I've created a put request. It already works, but I would like to check if update has really happened before sending a success response. So I've created a conditional for that ( if (!$product->update()) ), but it always returns 'true'. How can I check if any field has changed in a record?

```
 public function put()
{
    $id = $this->getParam('id');
    
    $input = $this->getRawData();
    
    $product = Product::findFirst([
        'conditions' => 'id = :id:',
        'bind' => ['id' => $id]
    ]);

    if ($product === null){
        throw new NotFoundException();
    }

    $product->assign($input);
    $product->update();

    if (!$product->update()) {
        $this->errorResponse($product->getMessages());
    } else {
        $this->successResponse($product->toArray($product->update()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not check for differences in the model? This could help to check why `update`  returns `true` Also, is your problem really related to MySQL or REST (which both seem to be irrelevant to me, as this is a common controller method without any such connection?)?

Comment: I think you should be able to use smth like [`mysqli_affected_rows()`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_affected_rows.asp#:~:text=Definition%20and%20Usage,%2C%20REPLACE%2C%20or%20DELETE%20query.)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling $product->update() three times. You do it once after the assign, then again for your if test, which is why it's always returning TRUE there I believe, and once inside the toArray() which may not actually return anything since the second and third updates don't have any data to update (not sure about that though).

I would code this as follows:

```
$product->assign($input);
$results = $product->update();

if (!results) {
    $this->errorResponse($product->getMessages());
} else {
    $this->successResponse($results->toArray());
}
```

I am assuming that the $product->assign($input); statement is working as expected to update the $product data for you.  I don't use that.  I prefer to do direct assignments for updates so nothing is left to chance, ie. $product->whatever = $input['whatever'];.

Give this a try and hopefully it will work as expected for you.

Comment: `assign` works very good, with the added advantage that it sanitizes the fields according to the model definitions. To use `$product->whatever = $input['whatever']` better use `$product->whatever = $this->filter->sanitize($input['whatever'], 'field_type');` (assuming that you have defined a filter service in your DI).

Comment: I need to add a small update to my answer above for the upcoming Phalcon 5 release. With Phalcon 5, the dev team decided to return NULL for no data found/updated instead of returning false like they have been doing for years with Phalcon 4 and back. So when you get to Phalcon 5, the test will need to be coded as follows:  if (empty(results)) {...}

Answer (score 0):

You can use Model Events, i.e. `afterUpdate` and `notSaved`, like:

```
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;
use Phalcon\Http\Response;

class ModelBase extends Model
{
    public function afterUpdate()
    {
        $response = new Response();
        $response->setJsonContent([
           'success' => true,
           'message' => "Record updated"
        ])->send();
    }

    public function notSaved()
    {
        $response = new Response();
        $response->setJsonContent([
           'success' => false,
           'message' => 'Record not saved'
        ])->send();
    }
}
```

The `Product` and all other models will extend `ModelBase`. Then your code could be:

```
public function put()
{ 
  $id = $this->getParam('id');

  $input = $this->getRawData();

  $product = Product::findFirst([
    'conditions' => 'id = :id:',
    'bind' => ['id' => $id]
  ]);

  if ($product === null){
    throw new NotFoundException();
  }

  $product->assign($input);
  $product->update();
}
```

And Phalcon event will respond if the model was updated or not. If you prefer, you can also use custom http response codes for `update` or `notSaved`. More information about `Model Events` in [the documentation](https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/en/db-models-events#model-events)